# Can someone explain the gap between these flex element children

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, flexbox

I'm trying to create a grid of div's inside of a flexbox element, yet despite my best efforts, there are still horizontal gaps between the rows of div's

(html, body set to full width; full height. No problems there)

Parent Styling:

```
#root{
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;

    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    align-items: flex-start;

    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

class for grid div's inside parent:

```
.grid_div{
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background: black;
    width: 58.8571px;
    height: 58.8571px;
    flex-grow: 0;
    flex-shrink: 0;
}
```

And here's the result:

[image: output from styling above]

What am I missing?

Full Document:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <title>time</title>

    <style>
        html, body{
            margin: 0;
            width: 100%;
            min-height: 100vh;
        }

        #root{
            position: fixed;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;

            display: flex;
            flex-flow: row wrap;
            justify-content: flex-start;
            align-items: flex-start;

            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;

        }
    </style>

    <script src="https://openbox.city/js/nested_js.js"></script>
    <script src="https://openbox.city/js/tranzit_js.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <main id="root"></main>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        Nested = new nested()
        Tranzit = new tranzit()

        const root = document.querySelector('#root')

        const gridZoom = {
            gridWidth: 7,
            gridHeight: 10,
            initialize(){
                this.createGrid()
            },
            createGrid(){

                const cellDimension = root.getBoundingClientRect().width / this.gridWidth
                const cell = this.library.cell(cellDimension)
                const amountOfCells = this.gridWidth * this.gridHeight
                for(i=0;i<amountOfCells;i++){
                    const cellClone = cell.cloneNode(true)
                    cellClone.dataset.id = i
                    root.appendChild(cellClone)
                }
            },
            library: {
                cell(dimension){
                    return Nested.parse({
                        tag: 'div',
                        attributes: {
                            class: 'grid_cell',
                            style: {
                                boxSizing: 'border-box',
                                display: 'inline-block',
                                background: 'blue',
                                border: '1px solid black',
                                width: `${dimension}px`,
                                height: `${dimension}px`,
                                flexGrow: 0,
                                flexShrink: 0
                            }
                        }
                    })
                }
            }
        }



        gridZoom.initialize()
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hard to say without being able to run your code. Could you create [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for us?

Comment: Absolutely. It's just a testing document, so I'll paste the whole document.

Comment: @Jacob: please don't just "*post the whole document,*" only post the minimal relevant portion of your code required to demonstrate and reproduce your problem. Too much code often obfuscates, or confuses, the actual problem you're looking to solve.

Comment: I've already. It's very very small. Like I said, just a testing document. I will strip it down if need be.

Answer (score 1):

Set up height to auto. It will maybe solve your problem.

```
 #root{
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    align-items: flex-start;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

Comment: It did. Thank you. Let's say I needed #root to fill the viewport though. Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 1):

Looks fine [here](https://codepen.io/raul-rogojan/pen/mdLOgmo?editors=1000). I have removed the flex-grow and flex-shrink. It's hard to see the problem if I can't reproduce it. Have you tried `*{margin: 0, padding: 0}` or `row-gap: 0` ?

```
style {
    boxSizing: 'border-box',
    display: 'inline-block',
    background: 'blue',
    border: '1px solid black',
    width: `${dimension}px`,
    height: `${dimension}px`,
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`align-content`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/align-content) property to control the vertical space between wrapped rows.
In your case you need `align-content: flex-start` to pull all rows to the top.

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

#root {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: flex-start;
  align-content: flex-start;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<main id="root"></main>
<script src="https://openbox.city/js/nested_js.js"></script>
<script src="https://openbox.city/js/tranzit_js.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  Nested = new nested()
  Tranzit = new tranzit()

  const root = document.querySelector('#root')

  const gridZoom = {
    gridWidth: 7,
    gridHeight: 10,
    initialize() {
      this.createGrid()
    },
    createGrid() {

      const cellDimension = root.getBoundingClientRect().width / this.gridWidth
      const cell = this.library.cell(cellDimension)
      const amountOfCells = this.gridWidth * this.gridHeight
      for (i = 0; i < amountOfCells; i++) {
        const cellClone = cell.cloneNode(true)
        cellClone.dataset.id = i
        root.appendChild(cellClone)
      }
    },
    library: {
      cell(dimension) {
        return Nested.parse({
          tag: 'div',
          attributes: {
            class: 'grid_cell',
            style: {
              boxSizing: 'border-box',
              display: 'inline-block',
              background: 'blue',
              border: '1px solid black',
              width: `${dimension}px`,
              height: `${dimension}px`,
              flexGrow: 0,
              flexShrink: 0
            }
          }
        })
      }
    }
  }

  gridZoom.initialize()
</script>
```